# Error de servidor en requestAsync Guzzle - Livewire

Tags: laravel, api, guzzle, livewire

Tengo una peticion GET asincrona que estoy realizando con GuzzleHttp

```
 $promise = $this->cliente->requestAsync('GET', $this->base_uri . $this->catalogs_uri . $catalog);
        $promise->then(
            function (ResponseInterface $res) {
                return $res;
            },
            function (RequestException $err) {
                return $err;
            }
        );
        $response = $promise->wait();
        return json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
```

En Tinker y postman **SI** recibo los datos, el problema está en cuando lo implemento  en Livewire obtengo el siguiente error

> Server error: `GET http://xxx.test/api/catalogs/payment-terms` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response: <!-- Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table &#03 (truncated...) (View: C:\laragon\www\xxxx\resources\views\livewire\xxx\xxxx\index.blade.php)

En el controlador de Livewire:

```
 public function mount()
{
    $this->cliente = new Cliente();
    $this->payment_terms = Tron::getClientCatalog('payment-terms');
}
```

¿Habrá que añadir algo al header?

Comment: Y la tabla como se llama?

Comment: No creo que sea tanto problema de la tabla porque en Tinker y postman si obtiene los datos.

Comment: Pues considero que si desde el momento que el mensaje de error indica que no puede encontrar la tabla o vista indicada

Comment: Por ejemplo el modelo se llama Cliente, entonces ¿cómo se llama la tabla?

Comment: Ese mensaje es del servidor en todo caso sería en donde esta alojado el API ya revise el código de la api y  tiene seteado el nombre de la tabla con protected $table

Comment: Y en tinker qué pones exactamente?